# Entity Framework 4: How to get excluded Views to map to diagram if the update from database removes them?

Tags: sql-server-2005, entity-framework-4, mapping

I got this error:

```
"The table/view 'database.dbo.table' does not have a primary key defined and no
valid primary key could be inferred. This table/view has been excluded. To use 
the entity, you will need to review your schema, add the correct keys, and 
uncomment it."
```

So, I un-commented it, added EntityKeys, EntityTypes, and a query.  Everything worked fine, until I "Update Model From Database", which erased all my changes.

How can you get Entity Framework to recognize the view under the "Update Model From Database"?  Is there anything you can add to the Microsoft SQL 2005 view so that EF could pickup as the primary key fields?

My view only has two fields:

```
ID int not null, -- PK
SKU int null
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a known EF Designer limitation. The Store part of the model is regenerated by the Update Model From Database wizard, this is the reason of the problem.
This problem was already discussed at the Devart Entity Framework Support forum [here](http://www.devart.com/forums/viewtopic.php?t=19776).